# Where is libSystem.dylib located on iOS5?

Tags: ios5, libsystem

I am doing research on how jailbreaking of iphone is done, so that I can propose some security mechanisms for raising the bar against such attacks.

On iOS5, I have noticed that system shared libraries (such as libSystem.B.dylib) don't exist at all! I ran 'find' at the top-level of my rooted phone and got none of the system shared libraries (or even the framework binaries).

When I run otool -L  I see that the app is linked with the system shared libraries which are supposed to be under /usr/lib/ of the phone and the frameworks under /System/Library/Frameworks/..

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. From 3.1, the system shared libraries are bundled together and stored in /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv6 (or _armv7) for some performance optimization reasons.

Ref: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Dyld_shared_cache